# Date and timepicker doesnot work

Tags: javascript

I add this javascript code to select date and time.But it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime">
        <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
            format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: true,
            pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: You should explain what library you are using (there're at least a dozen mayor ones).

Comment: @MarioRuiz jQuery UI Datepicker does not seem to have a `pickerPosition` option, he must be using some other library.

Comment: Well, you didn't even read the jquery docs :P

Comment: To whoever googles here: this is **not jQuery UI Datepicker**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the required js files?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Feeding an internet search engine with the the property names in your code suggests you are using [Bootstrap Datepicker by Sebastien Malot](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php). More specifically, it's a verbatim copy of the [Positionning](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php#demo_position) example in the plug-in site.

To figure out what's going wrong you first need to check the browser console (not sure what your browser is but you can try <kbd>F12</kbd>). Since it's an exact copy of the sample code you'll most likely didn't care downloading it.

Apparently, the plugin author forgot to document the installation process as well as the dependencies. It seems it requires jQuery and, having a Bootstrap on its name, it may also need [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).